# break layout when using <s:checkbox/> of STRUTS2

Tags: checkbox, struts2

I have problem with using tag **s:checkbox** need help!!!

I using tag **s:checkbox** but when run it auto insert tag "tr" and "td"  lead to break layout :

**JSP :**
[Click here to display img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6LAn.png)
**When display on browser**
[Click here to display img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4tL8.png)

Please , help me to fixed it.
Thanks!

Comment: S2's default theme adds (simplistic) formatting. Use a different theme, create a custom theme, or do this part more-manually.

Answer (score 0):

What i think you are looking for is

```
theme="simple"
```

Add this too the element